# How to disable one check box if other is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, radio-button

I have the form with 4 rows and each row has 10 cells. Each cell has 2 check boxes. If one check box is checked i would like do disable the other check box and other way around. Here is example of what I have:

```js
$(".myTbl input:checkbox").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings("input:checkbox").prop("checked", false);
});
```

```css
table.myTbl {
  width: 100%;
}

table.myTbl td {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="myTbl">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra0m" id="frmra0m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra0nr" id="frmra0nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra0" id="frmra0" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra1m" id="frmra1m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra1nr" id="frmra1nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra1" id="frmra1" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra2m" id="frmra2m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra2nr" id="frmra2nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra2" id="frmra2" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra3m" id="frmra3m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra3nr" id="frmra3nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra3" id="frmra3" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra4m" id="frmra4m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra4nr" id="frmra4nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra4" id="frmra4" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra5m" id="frmra5m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra5nr" id="frmra5nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra5" id="frmra5" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra6m" id="frmra6m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra6nr" id="frmra6nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra6" id="frmra6" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra7m" id="frmra7m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra7nr" id="frmra7nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra7" id="frmra7" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra8m" id="frmra8m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra8nr" id="frmra8nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra8" id="frmra8" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra9m" id="frmra9m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra9nr" id="frmra9nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra9" id="frmra9" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra10m" id="frmra10m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra10nr" id="frmra10nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra10" id="frmra10" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I was thinking about radio buttons but there is a problem. Radio button can't be unchecked. If anyone can provide any advise or solution for this problem please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried anything yet other than radio buttons?

Comment: Please publish your JS too.

Comment: @KevinKloet I was thinking about drop down menu.

Comment: Why not just use `input type="radio"` elements? You get this behaviour for free when you given them the same `name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the siblings using the jQuery [`siblings`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) function and uncheck them. Btw I assume you mean uncheck and not disable?

e.g.

```js
$(".mtTbl input:checkbox").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings("input:checkbox").prop("checked", false);
});
```

```css
table.myTbl {
  width: 100%;
}

table.myTbl td {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="mtTbl">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra0m" id="frmra0m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra0nr" id="frmra0nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra0" id="frmra0" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra1m" id="frmra1m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra1nr" id="frmra1nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra1" id="frmra1" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra2m" id="frmra2m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra2nr" id="frmra2nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra2" id="frmra2" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra3m" id="frmra3m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra3nr" id="frmra3nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra3" id="frmra3" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra4m" id="frmra4m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra4nr" id="frmra4nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra4" id="frmra4" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra5m" id="frmra5m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra5nr" id="frmra5nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra5" id="frmra5" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra6m" id="frmra6m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra6nr" id="frmra6nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra6" id="frmra6" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra7m" id="frmra7m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra7nr" id="frmra7nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra7" id="frmra7" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra8m" id="frmra8m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra8nr" id="frmra8nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra8" id="frmra8" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra9m" id="frmra9m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra9nr" id="frmra9nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra9" id="frmra9" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra10m" id="frmra10m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra10nr" id="frmra10nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra10" id="frmra10" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have tried your example and works great! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

you can use jquery to implement this..

```js
$('.mtTbl input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).siblings( 'input[type="checkbox"]' ).attr('disabled',true);
        }
              
});
```

```css
table.myTbl {
 width: 100%;
}
table.myTbl td {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 1px;
 margin: 0px;
 background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="mtTbl">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra0m" id="frmra0m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra0nr" id="frmra0nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra0" id="frmra0" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra1m" id="frmra1m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra1nr" id="frmra1nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra1" id="frmra1" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra2m" id="frmra2m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra2nr" id="frmra2nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra2" id="frmra2" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra3m" id="frmra3m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra3nr" id="frmra3nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra3" id="frmra3" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra4m" id="frmra4m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra4nr" id="frmra4nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra4" id="frmra4" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra5m" id="frmra5m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra5nr" id="frmra5nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra5" id="frmra5" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra6m" id="frmra6m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra6nr" id="frmra6nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra6" id="frmra6" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra7m" id="frmra7m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra7nr" id="frmra7nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra7" id="frmra7" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra8m" id="frmra8m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra8nr" id="frmra8nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra8" id="frmra8" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra9m" id="frmra9m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra9nr" id="frmra9nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra9" id="frmra9" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra10m" id="frmra10m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra10nr" id="frmra10nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra10" id="frmra10" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Anyways you should use radio buttons ....

Comment: How I can uncheck radio button?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.mtTbl input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).siblings( 'input[type="checkbox"]' ).attr('disabled',true);
        }else {
            $(this).siblings( 'input[type="checkbox"]' ).attr('disabled',false);
        }
              
});
```

```css
table.myTbl {
 width: 100%;
}
table.myTbl td {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 1px;
 margin: 0px;
 background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="mtTbl">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra0m" id="frmra0m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra0nr" id="frmra0nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra0" id="frmra0" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra1m" id="frmra1m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra1nr" id="frmra1nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra1" id="frmra1" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra2m" id="frmra2m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra2nr" id="frmra2nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra2" id="frmra2" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra3m" id="frmra3m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra3nr" id="frmra3nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra3" id="frmra3" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra4m" id="frmra4m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra4nr" id="frmra4nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra4" id="frmra4" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra5m" id="frmra5m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra5nr" id="frmra5nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra5" id="frmra5" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra6m" id="frmra6m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra6nr" id="frmra6nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra6" id="frmra6" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra7m" id="frmra7m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra7nr" id="frmra7nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra7" id="frmra7" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra8m" id="frmra8m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra8nr" id="frmra8nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra8" id="frmra8" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra9m" id="frmra9m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra9nr" id="frmra9nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra9" id="frmra9" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra10m" id="frmra10m" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra10nr" id="frmra10nr" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra10" id="frmra10" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: $('.mtTbl input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).siblings( 'input[type="checkbox"]' ).attr('disabled',true);
        }else {
            $(this).siblings( 'input[type="checkbox"]' ).attr('disabled',false);
        }
              
});

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function chk(idd) {
    idd=idd.id;
    if (idd[idd.length-1]=='m') {
        var c=idd.substr(0,idd.length-1) + 'nr';
        if (document.getElementById(c).disabled)document.getElementById(c).disabled=false;
        else document.getElementById(c).disabled=true;

    }
    else{
        var c=idd.substr(0,idd.length-2) + 'm';
        if (document.getElementById(c).disabled)document.getElementById(c).disabled=false;
        else document.getElementById(c).disabled=true;

    }
}
```

```
   <table class="mtTbl">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra0m" id="frmra0m" onclick="chk(this)" /><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra0nr" id="frmra0nr" onclick="chk(this)" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra0" id="frmra0" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra1m" id="frmra1m" onclick="chk(this)"/><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra1nr" id="frmra1nr" onclick="chk(this)" /><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra1" id="frmra1" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra2m" id="frmra2m" onclick="chk(this)"/><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra2nr" id="frmra2nr" onclick="chk(this)"/><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra2" id="frmra2" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra3m" id="frmra3m" onclick="chk(this)"/><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra3nr" id="frmra3nr" onclick="chk(this)"/><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra3" id="frmra3" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra4m" id="frmra4m" onclick="chk(this)"/><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra4nr" id="frmra4nr" onclick="chk(this)"/><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra4" id="frmra4" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra5m" id="frmra5m" onclick="chk(this)"/><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra5nr" id="frmra5nr" onclick="chk(this)"/><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra5" id="frmra5" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra6m" id="frmra6m" onclick="chk(this)"/><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra6nr" id="frmra6nr" onclick="chk(this)"/><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra6" id="frmra6" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra7m" id="frmra7m" onclick="chk(this)"/><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra7nr" id="frmra7nr" onclick="chk(this)"/><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra7" id="frmra7" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra8m" id="frmra8m" onclick="chk(this)"/><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra8nr" id="frmra8nr" onclick="chk(this)"/><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra8" id="frmra8" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra9m" id="frmra9m" onclick="chk(this)"/><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra9nr" id="frmra9nr" onclick="chk(this)"/><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra9" id="frmra9" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra10m" id="frmra10m" onclick="chk(this)"/><b>M</b>
      <input type="checkbox" name="frmra10nr" id="frmra10nr" onclick="chk(this)"/><b>NR</b><br>
      <input type="number" name="frmra10" id="frmra10" min="0" max="120" step="5" style="width:50px" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Just paste this code to your page, and also paste javascript code on the same page, and run on your browser.

If not working? Please reply. Thank you.

Comment: please add some description. only code are not good for most of the users